# Adding a new data set in SSRS with nested stored procedures

Tags: ssrs, ssrs-2012

I have spOne which builds a couple of global temp tables with over 500 lines of code. Normally it would return a single result set but I wanted to leverage the code for building the temp tables without duplicating it. So, I added a @showResults param and if it equals 0 then it will build the temp tables but not execute a SELECT statement against them.

Now I have spTwo which calls spOne in the beginning with @showResults = 0 and then continues the work it has to do before returning a single result set.

In SSRS, I am trying to add spTwo as a data set but it is auto-detecting spOne's result set even though it would not be executed given the param input.

How do I add spTwo as an SSRS data set?

**Updated:**

A representation of the stored procedures can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/jTPxvhbw).

Comment: Have you tried deleting all the auto created fields and manually adding the fields of spTwo?

Comment: Yes I tried to add the fields manually. For some reason, after clicking OK, the data set does not get created.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add the data set by putting it into the XML manually, the GUI refused to save the change.